# How to properly externalize configuration using environmental variables in apache karaf?

Tags: apache-karaf

I'm trying to achieve externalization of karaf's configuration. In accordance with [documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_environment_variables_system_properties) I should be able to achieve this using environmental variables, however it doesn't work for me as can be seen here:

[image: config not changed as expected]

or here:

[image: simple test from documentation]

Why this simple example don't work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. I'm pretty sure this is the source code for it: https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/karaf-4.3.0/config/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/config/core/impl/KarafConfigurationPlugin.java

Added in karaf 4.3.0 while I'm using 4.2.6 ;)

Quick check and this works in karaf 4.3.0.